# How to add wordpress theme default modal in wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, simplemodal

I'm using a wordpress theme which is using an inbuilt modal form for login/ register, I want that to be used in a specific menu item. There are lot of plugins to create popups and display. The thing is the modal which is comeup with the theme.

Login

I need a menu named Login which triggers this modal on click.

Comment: You should specify which theme you are using, the wordpress version, and a bit more context. A link could help also

Comment: dwt listing theme, 

<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Login</a> </li>